# Android app background fails to run on phone but works on android studio preview

Tags: android, background

Not sure why this is happening. first let me say this is a homework assignment (as I like to be open about this (we all have to learn somehow). it is not late or over due). The error I am getting is not part of my assignment, the assignment is done, I am now experimenting with things. I added a background image to my app. in the preview everything works fine.
 [image: how it previews in android studio]

but then when I run in on my Samsung Note 4 I get this
[image: on my note 4]

Here is my code...can someone tell me what the error could be?

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/cool_red_and_black_desktop_wallpaper_hd_3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your phone's resolution is higher. So you need to increase your image's resolution and add it in drawable-xxhdpi folder. Try this and see whether it works.